# comparator not found

Tags: java, comparator

I have to order a collection and I use a comparator

```
import java.util.*;

public class OpereComparatorAuthor implements Comparator<Opera>{

    public int compare(Opera left,Opera right){     
        return left.getArtist().compareTo(right.getArtist());
    }
}
```

but when i call it from another class:

```
Collections.sort(ordbyauthor,OpereComparatorAuthor);
```

I receive this error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable OpereComparatorAuthor
location: class Museo
    Collections.sort(ordbyauthor,OpereComparatorAuthor);
```

why?

Comment: You mention Salla in a comment. What is the relationship between Opera and Salla? Also, post more code around how you're calling sort, including the definition of the List

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass an object of the comparator:

```
Collections.sort(ordbyauthor, new OpereComparatorAuthor());
```

**Update:**

This is just a suggestion. Instead of defining a class, use **anonymous class** (which I think is a good candidate) for this kind of situation.

e.g.

```
//I am using Sala here instead of Opera as per your comment
Collections.sort(ordbyauthor, new Comparator<Sala>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Sala left, Sala right) {
        //do your comparision here according to your requirement
        //then return the result
    }
});
```

Comment: after having create the object I receive the error: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.util.LinkedList<Sala>,OpereComparatorAuthor)
location: class java.util.Collections
  Collections.sort(ordbyauthor,new OpereComparatorAuthor());

Comment: How are you declaring `ordbyauthor`? That comparator is not for `Sala`, it's for `Opera` as you have `implements Comparator<Opera>`.

You are passing list of `Sala`s and `Comparator` for `Opera`. The list and comparator should be for the same type either both for `Sala` or both for `Opera`.

Comment: Your Comparator is a Comparator<Opera>. It compares Opera instances. You're trying to use it to sort a List<Sala>. Use a Comparator<Sala> to compare Sala instances.